# How to add a component dynamically in the body using TypeScript function

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I want to add dynamically components tag to my page using a TypeScript function.

Something like `putThisComponentToBody(MyAngularComponent)`, that would append `<app-my-angular-component></my-angular-component>` to my DOM.

Excepted result in DOM :

Comment: The expected result in DOM is not showing. Also, you should be more specific on your question and what you're expecting to get. There are many ways to insert components on the DOM in angular.

Comment: Could you write few ways to do that please ?

Comment: Angular team already did it. On angular.io, under `Fundamentals >> Components & Template` you may find some guides on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still didn't solve my problem...

Comment: The answer is there, you just need to read through it. If you do read the documentation, do it yourself and face a specific issue, please post it here and we will be glad to help.

Comment: In order for us to help you, we will need more details on what you are attempting to accomplish. Please put more explanation in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To add components dynamically at run time you will have to use some container which will be used to attach your component. Please go through this link - https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader